# Sanity io No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: reactjs, xmlhttprequest, sanity

[enter image description here][1]I am having trouble getting my Sanity io posts to render. This is the error I am getting this error.

```
post:1 
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://wuj77i1.api.sanity.io/v1/data/query/production?query=*' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

browser-request.js:117 
  
GET https://wuj77i1.api.sanity.io/v1/data/query/production?query=*\ net::ERR_FAILED 403
```

Can you recommend any solutions to overriding the CORS Origin?
I have added the localhost of my React Project to allow credentials but I am still getting this error.

Images of the Error message [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJCyQ.jpg

Comment: "I have added the localhost of my React Project to allow credentials" in the Sanity manage dashboard (API -> CORS Origins)? If not that is likely the issue.

Comment: @corygibbons I have done that already and I am still getting the error unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `projectId` is incomplete (it should be eight characters but there are only seven) in your client configuration. You're getting a CORS error because you're trying to get data from a project that doesn't have CORS origins set (since it doesn't exist).

Answer (score 0):

I had a CORS problem too - I had added https://localhost:3000/ to CORS origins in Sanity.io with Credentials set to allowed but still got the error.  My mistake was having the wrong Project ID.

(**Note I'm using ViteJS instead of NPM)

Click on the copy beside the Project ID ->

[image]

Then paste it in your .env file, right beside REACT_APP_SANITY_PROJECT_ID

[image]

Finally, in your Sanity client.js file make sure you are pointing to the correct environment variable.

[image]